# Maximum power transfer of transformer

Tags: transformer, ac, signal, signal-processing

We have this transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnrpVE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The power transfered to R1 resistor is maximized when the frequency of the signal is very big.This means   it is not useful to use the same circuit for low frequency signals?

If I want to send a low frequency signal and want as much power as possible to be transfered to R1 resistor how do I achieve it?

Comment: What frequency does this operate at?

Comment: Big frequency maximises power? No. Not useful for low frequency? Incorrect. How do you send power? Specify what frequency it's at, what amount you want to send, and for bonus points what other 'goodness' factors there are like efficiency, distortion, noise etc.

Comment: What transformer is it? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Neil_UK big frequency maximizes power because big frequency means rapidly changing current in the left part of the transformer-> big voltage induced to the right part of the transformer.Low frequency means slowly changing current in the left part of the transformer -> slow voltage induced to the right part of the transformer.And power is sent through electromagnetic induction.Read how transformers work.

Comment: @Andyaka it is a common transformer and I want to be able to send as much power as possible from the left side of the transformer to the right side of the transformer for low frequencies.

Comment: The devil is in the detail - provide details as requested in **ALL** the above comments.

Comment: Hmm a transformer operates at all frequencies just at low frequencies the power sent from the left coil to the right coil is smaller. Can I use another circuit when at low frequencies the most power will be transmitted at low frequencies?

Comment: I will remove my vote to close if much more detail is provided such as approximate frequncy range and desired amount of power to transfer. Because you show an antenna, I think maybe you are considering RF frequencies? But it is not clear. Some audio tranformers may pass 20 Hz. Some microwave transformers may pass 20 GHz. But they are very different.

Comment: i really don't understand.

Comment: _"This means it is not useful to use the same circuit for low frequency signals?"_ - Correct. But 'low'' is not a specification. What frequency do you consider to be 'low'?

Comment: Low omg do I need to give a number?

Comment: @McCarter yes. How is that even surprising?

Comment: @McCarter and your insistence that high frequency current has more power really betrays that you haven't enjoyed basic electronics, but are still trying to implement a radio. As said before, that won't work out. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I didnt expect something more.

Comment: @McCarter It is absolutely logical that you can't expect an answer to something based on false statements!

Comment: Okay whatever bruh.

Comment: Marcus Muller transfer of high frequency signals is better than transfer of low frequency signals. I think you don't know the intuition behind electronics only "let's solve the equations and see what happens" so you cant judge me and this question has nothing to do to build a radio you are assuming lot of things which are not correct.

Comment: @McCarter you said: *you cant judge me and this question has nothing to do to build a radio* - yet your circuit diagram shows a picture of an antenna? And you've even called it "ANT1".

Comment: @Andyaka antennas are not used only for radios.

Comment: reviewing questions and comments is what makes this page have high quality. I will hence not stop doing my part in moderation here.

Comment: also, you might want to read up on Dunning-Kruger. I hope it doesn't bite you in real life! (it's really unpleasant dealing with you here, I think I'll mute you out and not try to help you improve questions in the future, but directly vote to close, as there doesn't seem to be a basis for hope that you might improve your questions. If you can intuit better than people who studied this stuff for years can engineer, why are you even asking?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110012/discussion-on-question-by-mccarter-maximum-power-transfer-of-transformer).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to transfer a sinus signal.

The same circuit may be used for low and higher frequencies, but you may need a different transformer rated for the used frequency.

The maximum transferable power is proportional to the core weight of the transformer and to the used frequency.

The same transformer used for 400 Hz instead of 50 Hz may transfer 8 times the power, if the coils are designed for that current.

You need a much heavier tranformer to transfer the same power at 50 Hz instead of 400 Hz.

A transformer designed for 60 Hz only may be a bit too small for 50 Hz. A transformer designed for 50 Hz will work well with 60 %.

But transformers for much higher frequencies than some ten kHz are a different thing.

Comment: How can a transformer be designed for a certain frequency?

Comment: You need to know the certain frequency and the maximum power to select a proper core size. If the windings would not fit into that core a larger one is needed. It is not so easy to design a good transformer.